# Jenkins with MSTest plugin : "mstest xml coverage report file not found"

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage, mstest

In my build process, the VsTest.console tests my dll and generates a `TestResults\a.trx` file. The only parameter I added (more than dll path) is a .runsettings file.

The .trx file is not empty, the xml inside is quite explicit about what have been done. Double-clicking on the trx file opens vs2013 and results + coverage are displayed as it should.

Then, I want to publish the coverage results with jenkins  [MSTest plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin) but it fails because it looks for a file that does not exists. Here are the output log :

```
MSTest: Processing tests results in file(s) TestResults\a.trx
MSTest: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\tepp\TestResults\a.trx
mstest xml coverage report file not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\tepp\TestResults\mstest-coverage.xml
```

Should it be better to use the MSTest-runner plugin ?

If not, what did I missed in my build process ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems converting MSTest code covarage results in to XML

Have you tried something like TRX2HTML or TRXER ? (The convert them to htm so you can view using publish artifacts plugin)

[TRXER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593251/convert-trx-into-html-using-trxer)

[TRX2HTML](https://trx2html.codeplex.com/)

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288414/convert-mstest-code-covarage-results-in-to-xml)

Can you tell me your build steps?

Comment: MSTest plugin has been upgraded and works fine with visual studio 2015. I still need to do the conversion myself but the tutorials on the plugin webpage are working pretty well.