# Convert Trx into Html using TRXER

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, trx

Just released a new tool called TRXER.
Git link :https://github.com/NivNavick/trxer
All it does is tramsform TRX file (mstest results file) into html.
The Html as shown below is clean,nice and understandable.
You can see the pie indicates statuses count and a table that includes test classes that contains the tests themselves.

[image: This is how it looks like]

You can view the release note here 
https://github.com/NivNavick/trxer

Hope you will love this product and find it useful.
Best regards :)

Comment: Close Reason: Its advertising for an external product

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you very much :)

Comment: Its advertising for an external product

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is blatant advertising.

Comment: this is definitely a self ad, but anyway, nice stuff! just tried and good for its purpose :) thx

Answer (score 4):

[image: Almost there..]

Nice work!

The "Show Tests" link works right ?

Comment: Yes of course.
Can you upload the TRX file so I can see why the Pie and the failed tests not showing up?

Comment: I know why there are no statuses and pie !!
You are using Internet Explorer.
Try using other browsers such as Chrome and Firefox that supports HTML 5 Canvas.

Comment: Hey both works! The problem was internet explorer {as always} Anyway i'll implement your report on our Jenkins servers but the lack of internet explorer is a small problem since most organisations use (including us) internet explorer as the main web browser.

Anyway good work !!!

Comment: New release (v1.0.0.2) fully supports Internet Explorer!!
https://github.com/NivNavick/trxer/releases/tag/v1.0.0.2
Let me know if everything alright

Answer (score 1):

For all the people who are having issues converting .trx files generated on new Visual Studio versions above 2015. I have created a new release to fix the unhandled exception (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException) and transform .trx files generated up to Visual Studio 2022:

The link to the release: https://github.com/gorkalertxundi/trxer/releases/tag/vsstudio-2022