# Developing my first Jenkins Plugin (Need advice/resources)

Tags: jenkins

At my workplace, I've been tasked to look into some metrics that the Jenkins tool provides and somehow pull them programatically and display them in some presentable format. The metrics that I need to pull are:

- How many unit tests are passing? Failing? Skipping? The total % of passing?
- How many integration tests are passing? Failing? Skipping? The total % of passing?
- How many acceptance tests are passing? Failing? Skipping? The total % of passing?
- How long does it take to execute the test? Make the build?
- What is the number of tests executing in pipelines?
  ... the list goes on

Now I have a very small 1000 ft understanding of Jenkins, and an even smaller understanding of the steps that I need to take to make this program come to life. I am an intern with not much programming experience either, but after some research, I learned that I can navigate through the Jenkins API by adding '.../api' to the link that I want to find API elements for, and I know that I'm going to need to develop a plugin. Aside from that I don't have much direction at all. I don't know what environment I need to develop these plugins (Maven? Never heard of it)... I don't know what languages are supported (I only know C++, Java, and JS)... I don't know how to even install a plugin or get to the plugin on the Jenkins site. I feel like I'm drinking from a firehose with this task and need some guidance.

Does anyone have good guides, advice, tips, tricks, videos... anything that might help me get started on Jenkins plugin development? Any insight into how I might solve this problem too would be much appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extend+Jenkins  + http://www.wakaleo.com/books/jenkins-the-definitive-guide ... Start with the first 2 chapters of the book. Its a tutorial of how to setup and manage jenkins. After that you can explore freely

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are tools out there which generates HTML reports. You can start there.

For example: MSTest report (.trx) can be converted to HTML by [TRXER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593251/convert-trx-into-html-using-trxer)

and can be published using the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin)

However if you're into building your own plugin use [NetBeans](https://github.com/stapler/netbeans-stapler-plugin) (I have tried it; and it works)

[image]

[image]

But creating Jenkins graphs you have to google and see.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how I would go about using the HTML reports and MSTest? I have no experience with both technologies

Comment: It's like this. Imagine you have a C# application and you write unit tests using MSTest or NUnit. In Jenkins you have plugins which can read the unit test result report and give a graph. (Anyway use an available plugin) 

However what you wanted (passing? Failing? Skipping?) can be MORE GRAPHICALLY represented if you used a tool to convert the unit test result to a HTML page. It's the same thing as using the plugin but more data is visually presented.