# Pie Chart is not viewing in the HTML reports after converting from .trx with tool TRXER

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, winappdriver

I have converted the .trx file to HTML reports but pie chart is not showing on html reports. I have Chrome 79+ version. I created html reports after using this [StackOverflowLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593251/convert-trx-into-html-using-trxer)

In above link, it is mentioned that pie chart is viewed only when we have HTML5 canvas supported and Chrome 79+ support HTML5.

I am running below command on **Developer command prompt for VS 2019**

Generated .trx file with command:

```
vstest.console.exe UnitTest1.dll /logger:trx
```

I have executed below command to generate HTML reports from .trx file:

```
TrxerConsole.exe  \DesktopWithMSTest\bin\Debug\TestResults\TestResult.trx
```

Showing below error while converting to the HTML 
[image: Error_trx_into_HTML]

Answer (score 1):

A new version has been released on a different github page for VS versions greater than 2015. It fixes the above issue.

https://github.com/gorkalertxundi/trxer/releases/tag/vsstudio-2022